# Cross-type record with statements in F#?

Tags: types, f#, record

The following code does not compile:

```ml
type Person = 
  {
    FirstName : string
    LastName : string
  }

type Employee = 
  {
    FirstName : string
    LastName : string
    Salary : int
  }

let p : Person = 
  {
    FirstName = "Steve"
    LastName = "Jobs"
  }

let e : Employee = 
  {
    p with Salary = 1
  }
```

A work-around is to write a helper, perhaps like so:

```ml
let toEmployee (p : Person) : Employee = 
  {
    FirstName = p.FirstName
    LastName = p.LastName
    Salary = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
  }

let e : Employee = 
  {
    toEmployee p with Salary = 1
  }
```

But this is a bit tedious.

**Does F# offer a better way?**

This is a common thing to do in JavaScript, for example:

```js
const e = {
  ...p,
  salary: 1,
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a statically and nominally typed language this is not possible in F# and this is by intentional design.

Supposing you did have that feature like the JS and a value `let e = {...p; Salary = 1}`. Then suppose you rename a field on `Person`. What should the type of `e` be inferred to? What should the error message say? There aren't easy answers to this question, and it could become very complicated and hard to understand very fast in a larger codebase.

It's better to write out the new record manually. It's a bit more verbose but it fits the general F# theme of being more explicit in some dimensions, so that you can be less specific with annotating types (allowing more type inference). If you could be very implicit with both then it would create an explosion of complexity.

---

Another option which might help here is to change your model to put repeated fields into a separate type:

```
type Person = 
  { FirstName : string
    LastName : string }

type Employee = 
  { Person : Person
    Salary : int }

let p = 
  { FirstName = "Steve"
    LastName = "Jobs" }

let e = { Person = p; Salary = 1 }
```

In F# the way you model your types is very important and has a knock on effect on all of the code that uses it. So if your code seems wonky, consider if your types could be improved.

Comment: I don't think static typing makes this impossible, the type checker just needs to realize that the fields in one record type are a superset of the other. The fact that F# does not do this answers my question though.

Comment: I agree with sdgfsdh. It's not a question of static typing, Typescript is statically typed after all. Typescript uses structural typing so some types can be subtypes of others if they possess all members of the other. F# has structural equality though, so eh, you win some you lose some.

Comment: @Asti I didn't say it would be impossible because F# is statically typed, just that it doesn't fit the design of the language and the way it is used. I didn't want to get into too much detail, but you pointed out TypeScript has structural typing. F# has nominal typing so this feature is difficult to add on top in a way that interacts well with all existing features.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox That's a reasonable position. OCaml is structurally typed, but F# is nominally typed for interop, I guess. It would be okay to expect future implementations of structural typing for record types, which would make working with anonymous records easier.